# How to remove trailing 0s in a long

Tags: c++

How can I remove all the trailing zeros in a long?

e.g. 450000000 to 45, 2100 to 21

all numbers are positive if that makes any difference.

Comment: How would you do it with pen and paper?

Comment: I thought someone would already know, I didn't try anything yet. It's trying to solve a practical problem.. I have a variable # of trailing 0s which are not significant to me, resulting from a quick and dirty conversion from a double to a long. I guess I could put in code to detect the # of digits after a double - ignoring 0s, so as to know precisely what to multiply by (but from what I remember searching previously, this is not so easy).. so since it is just for logging I figured multiplying by a large enough amount, would result in a variable # of extra zeros but still acceptable.

Comment: Keep dividing the number by 10, until it’s no longer evenly divisible by 10

Comment: @yunnosch I would keep dividing by 10 but I was thinking there might be a better (more compact) solution that someone would know - I'm not that great at C++, so don't know all the features available.

Comment: Convert to `std::string` trim trailing `0`s convert to number type of choice.

Comment: You could also convert to a string and trim the trailing 0s. Not sure I’d call that easier though. I’d just write a remove trailing 0s utility function. That way you don’t really need to care what the implementation is, especially since it’s for logging.

Comment: `while (some_long % 10 == 0) some_long /= 10;`

Comment: @RichardCritten yes I'm thinking that is probably the way I need to go because actually without knowing the # of non-trailing zero decimals in the double, I don't know how to round the double so that I don't get something like 999 after multiplying instead of 1000

Comment: Dividing by 10 is probably the most **compact** approach: `while (x * 10 == 0) x /= 10;`. Can't get much more compact than that.

Answer (score 1):

First you need a more precise definition of *trailing zeros*. In a decimal representation, *“a trailing zero”* means *“divisibility by 10”*. (Similarly, you would consider divisibility by 2 for binary or by 16 for hexadecimal.) A number is divisible by 10 when the remainder after division by 10 (the result of the modulo (`%`) operation) is zero. To *“trim trailing zeros”* from a number in this sense, you would divide the number by the desired base as many times as needed, until it is no longer divisible by the base.

```cpp
uint64_t trim_zeros(uint64_t number, const uint64_t base = 10) {
  if (number == 0) return 0;  // or maybe throw something
  while (number % base == 0) number /= base;
  return number;
}
```

Comment: Need to check `number` is non-zero to avoid infinite loops

Answer (score 1):

With the help of modulo 10 , you can do this

```
void removeTrailingZeros(long& n)
{   while (n % 10 == 0)    n /= 10;  }
```

Comment: Need to check `number` is non-zero to avoid infinite loops